# Can we reach the same results with ogl and dx?

Tags: opengl, directx

Can we reach the same graphics results with OpenGL and DirectX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. OpenGL 4.1 and Direct3D 11 have equal functionality.